# How to create a cross-platform Ubuntu Touch app without qmlscene?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I have learned C++ and Qt to be able to create **cross-platform apps**.

I have a very simple app built as **executable** that runs on desktop but I can't figure out how to **make it work on my Ubuntu phone**.

All app examples I have found are executed via `qmlscene`, but I don't like that approach because I want to make my **app run on all OS supported by Qt**.

Here is the code:

- `CMakeLists.txt`

  ```
  project(testapp)
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

  set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
  set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
  set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

  find_package(Qt5Core  REQUIRED)
  find_package(Qt5Gui   REQUIRED)
  find_package(Qt5Qml   REQUIRED)
  find_package(Qt5Quick REQUIRED)

  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp main.qrc)
  qt5_use_modules(${PROJECT_NAME} Core Gui Qml Quick)

  install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION .)

  if(UNIX)
      add_subdirectory(ubuntu-package)
  endif(UNIX)
  ```
- `ubuntu-package/CMakeLists.txt`

  ```
  set(UBUNTU_MANIFEST_PATH "manifest.json.in" CACHE INTERNAL "Tells QtCreator location and name of the manifest file")

  set(APP_NAME    "${PROJECT_NAME}")
  set(APP_ID      "${PROJECT_NAME}.anonymous")
  set(ICON        "${PROJECT_NAME}.png")
  set(EXEC        "${PROJECT_NAME}")

  install(FILES "${PROJECT_NAME}.apparmor" "${ICON}" DESTINATION .)

  configure_file(manifest.json.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/manifest.json)
  install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/manifest.json DESTINATION .)

  set(DESKTOP_FILE_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}.desktop")
  configure_file(${DESKTOP_FILE_NAME}.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${DESKTOP_FILE_NAME})
  install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${DESKTOP_FILE_NAME} DESTINATION .)
  ```
- `main.cpp`

  ```
  #include <QGuiApplication>
  #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

      QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
      engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

      return app.exec();
  }
  ```
- `main.qml`

  ```
  import QtQuick 2.4
  import QtQuick.Window 2.1
  import Ubuntu.Components 1.3

  Window {
      minimumHeight: units.gu(80)
      minimumWidth: minimumHeight
      MainView {
          applicationName: "simpleapp"
          anchors.fill: parent
          Page {
              Button {
                  anchors.centerIn: parent
                  text: "Quit"
                  onClicked: Qt.quit()
              }
          }
      }
      Component.onCompleted: show()
  }
  ```

[The complete source code](https://github.com/moldcraft/testapp/tree/95225945f44159f4292feada69431a7f55e2cf33)

When I try to build it in Qt Creator for `armhf` kit, it throws errors:

```
CMakeFiles/testapp.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_end_cleanup@@CXXABI_1.3'
/var/lib/lxd/containers/device-armhf/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 error: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps that are on Ubuntu phone are open-source. Most of them don't use `qmlscene`. Terminal, for example: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-terminal-dev/ubuntu-terminal-app/trunk/files

You can clone that repository, compile yourself and see how it's done.

As for `undefined reference to symbol '__cxa_end_cleanup@@CXXABI_1.3'` - it seems that the toolchain is doing something wrong. In CMake settings set `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` to `ON` to see more logs. Or see if you can run CMake build from command line in that LXD container without QtCreator (then you can fiddle with individual compiler and linker commands).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/831213/432861